# ISC DHCP server: how many IPs are in use?

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcp

I'm wondering what is the correct way to count how many IPs are in use in my network according to the dhcpd process.

Is it just a matter of counting "binding state active" lines in dhcpd.leases file? Or it is something more complicated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ReportDHCP](http://www.omar.org/opensource/reportdhcp/) which parses your dhcp.leases file and provides you with a [report](http://www.omar.org/opensource/reportdhcp/genstats.html) that should give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

dhcpd-pools is probably what you want.

Example: `dhcpd-pools -c 'path-to-dhcpd.config' -l 'path-to-lease-file' -L11 -sp -r`

Explanation: It prints 'Range Headers' and 'Ranges' with '-L11' and then sorts recursively on 'percent' with '-sp -r'

Man page: http://dhcpd-pools.sourceforge.net/man.html

Answer (score -3):

use at the command-line:
Netsh dhcp server scope 192.168.1.0 show clients

Comment: `netsh: command not found`

Comment: JGrave, this question is not about Windows DHCP.